# How can I specialise a template with a template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Consider a template class

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
};
```

for which I can write a simple specialisation

```
template<>
class Foo<int>
{
};
```

I have a situation where I want to specialise Foo with a template class, in detail with a bool which serves as a compile-time flag:

```
template<>
class Foo<int, bool> // Clearly not the correct notation.
{

}
```

Uses would include Foo<1, true> and Foo<1, false>.

What is the correct notation for the class name, where I've marked "Clearly not the correct notation."?

I code to the C++11 standard.

Comment: `Foo<T>` and `Foo<T, E>` are different templates.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "I want to specialise Foo with a template class" but you might want to specialize with a type that encodes both types, like `Foo<std::tuple<int, bool>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like default value for template argument.

```
template<class T, bool flag = false>
class Foo
{
};

template<>
class Foo<int>
{
    //"false" specialization (default)
};

template<>
class Foo<int, true>
{
    //"true" specialization
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the primary template to

```
template<class T, bool B>
class Foo
{
};
```

and then you can specialize it like

```
template<>
class Foo<int, true>
{
};

template<>
class Foo<int, false>
{
};
...
```

and then you would use it like

```
Foo<int, true> FooT;
Foo<int, false> FooF;
```

---

If you are going to use values for the first parameter like

```
Foo<1, true>
```

Then the primary template should be

```
template<int I, bool B>
class Foo
{
};
```

and then you can specialize it like

```
template<>
class Foo<1, true>
{
};

template<>
class Foo<1, false>
{
};
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll do it this way.

Comment: @SasidiranSangamanautram I just noticed in your Q you want to use `Foo` like `Foo<1, true>`.  Is that really what you want to use `Foo`?

Comment: Almost yes, the first argument is actually an enum but I simplified it to an int.

Comment: @SasidiranSangamanautram Okay.  I've added to the answer how to get that since what I first proposed is different.

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly possible. Your template wants a single parameter, you can't specialize it for two. However, you can (partially) specialize it for some other type which is a template of two parameters.

Example:

```
template<class T>
class Foo;

template<int, bool> class tag;

template<int>
class Foo<tag<int, true>> { ... };

template<int>
class Foo<tag<int, false>> { ... };
```

And than you can use it

```
Foo<tag<1, true>> foo;
```